# Subtract offset voltages of operational amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier

In the circuit below the two LM324 operational amplifiers are from the same IC.

The offset voltage of each op-amp is specified to be up to 7 mV at 25 ºC.
The offset voltage mismatch is not specified or I could not find it.

Can I expect the difference of offset voltages (VM1) to partially cancel out?
Or should I assume the worst m-case VM1 of up to 14 mV?

Can I expect VM1 not to drift with temperature?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI2Haa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: try: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359911/are-the-offset-voltages-in-a-dual-quad-op-amp-correlated

Comment: Thank you glen_geek, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/359938/315169 gives a reasoned answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

> Can i expect the difference of Offset Voltages (VM1) to partially cancel out?

No, but there is a chance you will get lucky.

> Or should i assume the worst case VM1 of up to 14 mV?

Yes, but there is a chance that you will be lucky.

> Can i expect VM1 not to drift with temperature?

No, but there is a chance that you will be lucky.

If you are designing something to be sold or used by someone else, or something which, if it fails, the failure will be expensive or cause injury or death, then you should *always* assume the worst case might happen.

If you are designing something purely for your own enjoyment, then the argument against taking a risk is a little less persuasive.

Answer (score 0):

No, because they've matched each offset as closely as possible.

I would expect the typical total mismatch to be roughly \$\sqrt{2}\$ higher than the typical mismatch in a single op-amp. Worst-case is double, of course.

It's possible that in some circumstances *changes* in offsets due to temperature gradients on the die might (systematically) tend to cancel out, depending on which op-amp(s) is/are causing the heating and which op-amps you choose to difference.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Thermal coefficient of offset will be 5-10x better than spec, constant relative offset won't be much better than spec.

As long as both op-amps in the package dissipate the same power, the thermal tracking between two op-amps will be very good, and there will be very little offset change as the ambient temperature changes. This can be easily an order of magnitude better than the thermal offset drift specs of a single op-amp.

The absolute value of the offset voltage can be quite well matched by design in some op-amp chips, but LM324 IIRC isn't one of them - and there are differences between manufacturers there as well, since there are many sources for that die.